# Authenticate Google Apps Script user via HTTP

Tags: google-apps-script

In the scenario of scripts that need authentication to run (run as service account, locked down sharing settings, etc) is there a way to authenticate as a Google user via an HTTP tool like cURL, UrlFetchApp, or even PowerShell scripts from Windows Server environments?

Comment: Are you talking about calling a script that is deployed as a web app with authentication? OR talking to other services from Apps Script with authentication.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of calling a web service built with Apps Script from another application, or even a PowerShell or Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do a little leg work on this one.

Firstly, when you publish your apps script, make sure to change the "who has access to the app" to something like "only myself".

Then you need to see what happens when you try to hit that URL from an external service without authenticating. There may be some help from the error codes you are likely to receive.

I imagine you can then use the following documents to Authenticate for Google Services IN GENERAL.  Then you will most likely have to pass a sessionID or Accesskey of some sort.  I only have a brief understanding of OAuth, but I do imagine that you may be able to set up a more permanent connection between your other server and your particular Google Apps Script.

I hope this helps.

Jacob